# Get name of the first child in a object

Tags: javascript

I have following Object:

```
bots: {
    bot_1: {
      [...]
    },
    bot_2: {
      [...]
    },
    bot_3: {
      [...]
    }
    ...
},
```

How could I get the name of the first child? In this case 'bot_1'. Thanks!

EDIT: I should have searched a bit more since it is a pretty basic question. I tried searching for the answer but I couldn't find it because I didn't know that it is called "property". Anyways, thanks for your help

Comment: `bot_1` is not the first child. Objects are unordered. The first key for one browser could differ to the next browser.

Comment: `name`? do you mean `key`?...`value`?...`blood type`? `Favorite color`?

Comment: I mean 'bot_1', but I'm not sure what it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
bots[Object.keys(bots)[0]];
```

to get the first key of your object. However, you may not get `bot_1` always since the keys are unordered

Comment: Important to note that object properties are not ordered so if you want it to always return "bot_1" you have to search the .keys() array.

Comment: @terpinmd: Yes, added the caution in my answer.

Comment: @Jan-PaulFarac: If it works, accept the answer.

Comment: I will, once StackOverflow lets me.. 7 minutes left